# Go AST: Why is FuncDecl.Recv is of type *FieldList

Tags: go, abstract-syntax-tree, godoc

In the `go/ast` [docs](https://pkg.go.dev/go/ast#FuncDecl) the type of `FuncDecl.Recv` is `*FieldList` instead of `*Field`. It parses multiple receivers just fine.

But compiler throws error on passing multiple recievers

`method has multiple receivers`

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SDB1aZLnHr_Y)(Uncomment line 13 to see error)

So is this a mistake? or is it there for future releases? Does it have any significance?

Comment: Formally the receiver declaration in the spec is a parameter list, probably that's why the `go/ast` package also uses a `FieldList`. But the spec also states the receiver section must declare a **single** non-variadic parameter. This may be an oversight, I don't see any significance to it.

Comment: Not a mistake, and I'd argue not even an oversight. As icza points out you'll find in the spec that `Receiver` is defined as `Parameters` which is defined as `"(" [ ParameterList [ "," ] ] ")"` and so on. This goes perfectly with the docs on `FieldList`: *"A FieldList represents a list of Fields, **enclosed by parentheses, curly braces, or square brackets**."* This means that, in this case at the least, `go/ast` conforms to the spec. And keep in mind that a list of 1 or even 0 items is still a perfectly sound list.

Comment: Note that the job of a parser is, generally, syntax analysis and the construction of the AST and nothing more. For example the parser will just as well let you parse stuff like `var i int = "foo"`.  Would you expect *that* to have some significance? *Semantic* analysis and type checking are done in subsequent stages of the compilation process.